# Why do I receive no data in the server from Android App?

Tags: php, android, http, http-headers, httpurlconnection

this should be a stupid mistake of mine, please help me figure it out.
I have a app which sends some messages to a php server, using POST, but there is no data,

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.2/");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream outputStream = null;
try {
    if (purchase != null) {
            outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            stream.write(postmess.getBytes()); // <<<< No effect ?!
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
        }
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null)
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {
                    // ...
                }
        }


        Log.d(TAG, "data 2 send:" + postmess);

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        // Get the response
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(TAG, "Sending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        Log.d(TAG, "Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //  result
        Log.d(TAG, "Response:" + response.toString());
```

in Server:

```
<?php
echo "POST = " . var_dump($_POST);
```

here is the log:

PostHTTPS﹕ data 2 send: "this is long text."

PostHTTPS﹕ Sending 'POST' request to URL : http://xx.xx.xx.xx

PostHTTPS﹕ Response Code : 200 // means OK

PostHTTPS﹕ Response:array(0) {}POST = array(0)

Comment: What does the server receive? What does the server send? I see no params.

Comment: @Mohsen: This is less of a comment on the question and more on using libraries to the the lower level networking stuff. Have you checked out Android Async Http: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: @WindsurferOak very nice suloution you have there, thank you

Comment: @greenapps as i have shown there almost nothing, var_dump returns array(0)